# Permissions Administration Module

Tags: 7, users, forms

Is there a working module for Drupal 7 to restyle `admin/people/permissions/list` to add more usable controls? Some serious boons to building a large site with lots of permissions:

- Incremental search/filtering of shown permissions
- Add/Remove/Toggle all permissions for a role (globally, or per module ­— one column, or part of a column)
- Grant/Revoke/toggle a permission to all roles (one table row)
- Collapsible/tabbed groups

Something like [Module Filter](http://drupal.org/project/module_filter), but meant for permissions administration, would be ideal.

I've tried a couple of modules, but haven't had much luck with them. E.g. the stable version of [Permission Select](http://drupal.org/project/permission_select) from 2009 (!) fails to do anything, while the development version at least adds its checkboxes (but clicking on them does nothing).

Short of writing my own module and/or hacking something in jQuery, is there some understated gem of a module out there I should be using for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [Fast Permissions Administration](http://drupal.org/project/fpa) module; it is like the Module Filter module, but for permissions.

> This module is here to alleviate frustration when trying to manage permissions in Drupal. By providing a better permissions interface hopefully a few innocent keyboards and mice can be saved.

You can filter on the module name with @module, or permission@module:

> Module filtering:
>   You can also filter on the module a permission belongs to using the @ symbol: permission@module.
>
> For example, if you want to show only permissions that contain the word admin for the comment module you would enter: admin@comment.

Comment: Didn't know about that module..would still be nice to get the module filter approach with permissions though.

Comment: I've tried this one. It **does** provide incremental searching/filtering of permissions, but only that. Also, you can't use it to filter the name of a module (bold heading), it only filters on permission names. This works okay in some cases, but it breaks user expectations (which is why I often have to disable it before training the client on the site). It's about the only thing providing this sort of functionality though, so maybe a patch (or six) adding the extra features is in order.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for this myself, and I've not been able to find anything (including the time to start writing a solution myself).

It might be worth looking through the source of [Module Filter](http://www.drupal.org/project/module_filter) to see if there's anything that you can port or contacting the maintainer of [Filter Perms](http://drupal.org/project/filter_perms) to see if they'd be willing to share maintainership of a stable D7 version.

Comment: Since I'm usually in the middle of some site build or other (or helping cow-orkers with theirs), my Copious Free Time isn't all it used to be. But permissions are so critical, it's a huge surprise to me something mature doesn't exist. It must be a common request. I had some custom jQuery for a while, but it bit-rotted.

Answer (score 2):

Today I've upgraded a few modules on my Drupal 7 site (views, ctools, ...), as well as Drupal's core. I was pleasently surprized to see that the permissions administration interface have been highly redesigned:

1. Groups are now initially collapsed.
2. The Table Header is always visible even if you scroll down.

This largely solved my issue.

The Fast Permissions Administration module didn't work for me - the javascript on the page was endlessly loading. The [Filter Perms](http://drupal.org/project/filter_perms) module works greatly - it's the best option with the highest usability.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various solutions as below.

- **Fast Permissions Administration** module
- collapsing modules via the **admin menu** module
- the new permissions-filtering functionality provided by the **module filter**

I can confirm that the [Filter permissions](https://drupal.org/project/filter_perms) is the best and recently probably the only solution with enhances performance of the `admin/people/permissions` page (which is the crucial feature).

> This module provides filters at the top of the Permissions page for
>   easier management when your site has a large amount of roles and/or
>   permissions. The module was originally created because the excessive
>   amount of checkboxes combined with some jquery activity was causing
>   "Unresponsive Script" js errors on every load and save of the
>   permissions page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://drupal.org/project/permission_select for these:

> Add/Remove/Toggle all permissions for a role (globally, or per module
>   ­— one column, or part of a column) Grant/Revoke/toggle a permission
>   to all roles (one table row)